# React useState and useEffect issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import pkceChallenge from 'pkce-challenge';
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';


function Login({ onLogin }) {

  const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies('accessToken');
  const [codeVerifier, setCodeVerifier] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const code = urlParams.get('code');
    if (code) {
      retrieveToken(code);
      window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, window.location.pathname);
    }
  }, [codeVerifier]);

  const handleLogin = () => {

    const challenge = pkceChallenge();
    setCodeVerifier(challenge.code_verifier);
  
    window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorize?' +
      'response_type=code&' +
      'client_id=client&' +
      'scope=openid&' +
      'redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:3000/login&' +
      'code_challenge=' +
      challenge.code_challenge +
      '&' +
      'code_challenge_method=S256';
  };

  const retrieveToken = (code) => {
    
    try {
      const response = axios.post(
        'http://localhost:8080/oauth2/token?' +
        'client_id=client&' +
        'redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:3000/login&' +
        'grant_type=authorization_code&' +
        'code=' + code + '&' +
        'code_verifier=' + codeVerifier
      );
      setCodeVerifier('');
      const accessToken = response.data.access_token;
      const options = {
        path: '/',
        expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + response.data.expires_in * 1000), 
      };
      setCookie('accessToken', accessToken, options);
      onLogin()
    } catch (err) {
      alert('Invalid Credentials');
    }
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
    </div>
  );
}


export default Login;
```

Current workflow: When user press login, authorization code will be delivered and right after i want to send a request to the /login with this authorize code and the code verifier that i have just set when the user pressed login, but the codeVerifier is always null. What is the problem?

Comment: It doesn't look like that effect should have `codeVerifier` as a dependency. At best, it should have the `location.search` as a dependency.

Comment: `codeVerifier` is not `null`, it's `{}` - the value you are initialising it with when the page loads. Including when the `/oauth2/authorize` redirects the browser back to your page.

Comment: @Bergi location.search doesn't work to be as a dependency cause it's a global and the error will be :  Unexpected use of 'location'  no-restricted-globals

Sorry, indeed it is not null, it's {}. My problem is that when useEffect() happens and retrieveToken() is being called, i don't have the value changed in codeVerifier and i don't know how can i make the codeVerifier change the value before useEffect its called.

Comment: Ok, `window.location.search` then to satisfy your linter… but it doesn't really matter

Comment: The problem is not that `codeVerifier` wouldn't change when you call `setCodeVerifier`. The problem is that you're setting it before the page reloads. You'll need to store it in localstorage or a cookie or something to preserve it.

Comment: I even tried with localStorage and sessionStorage and cookie, when retrieveToken happens, codeVerifier is not there, it's like retrieveToken happens before handleLogin, i think something is going on with this useEffect thing

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that attempt. How (and when) did you retrieve `codeVerifier` back from the storage?

Comment: i discovered the problem for session storage and local storage . If you access your app with localhost:3000 but redirect uri is 127.0.0.1:3000 it will see it as different domains so local storage and session storage will be reset, or have other values cached, so you should always use 127.0.0.1:3000.